# What is correct representation of homogenous coordinates?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, projective-space

I read from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194867/represent-point-at-infinity-by-homogeneous-co-ordinates) and understand that the homogenous coordinates is of the form $[x, y, z]$ which represents by square bracket.
Also read from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337820/what-is-the-relationship-between-projection-plane-and-projective-plane/4337850?noredirect=1#comment9047107_4337850) the homogenous coordinates is of the form $(x, y, z)$ which represents by first bracket.

My question is what is the right representations of homogenous coordinates or how both representations are right at the same time?

Comment: Wikipedia's ["Barycentric coordinate system" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) and Kimberling's [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) use the notation $x:y:z$. (I also happen to be using this notation in a note.) "Correct" mathematical notation is whatever the author decides best serves the reader. I'm personally trying to avoid "overloading" delimiters, and also seeking to reduce some visual clutter (my coords tend to be large rational expressions; *giant* surrounding parentheses can be off-putting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different people may write projective coordinates as $(x,y,z)$, $(x:y:z)$, $[x,y,z]$, or even $[x:y:z]$. All have the same meaning, as long as the context makes it clear that those are indeed projective coordinates (the first option may be confused by affine coordinates, but the space where those coordinates live is usually clear from the context).

I understand that you wished another answer, but it just doesn't exist. There's no "best" notation or "universally accepted" notation. As long as everyone understands what is being said, which is very often the case, all is fine.

Comment: Also, everything Lee Mosher said in your other post is perfect.

Comment: your statement "the first option may be confused by affine coordinates"-----The affine coordinates could be (x, y) , so how could we confuse, please give one example by which I can understand?

Comment: I am confusing this thing which is: suppose $(x,y, z)$  is the representations of homogenous coordinates then it belongs to $\mathbb R^3$ but $[x,y, z]$  is the representations of homogenous coordinates then it belongs to $P^2.$ So my question is homogenous coordinates belongs to which? $\mathbb R^3$ or $P^2$? It's very confusing. Please help me.

Comment: Let's forget about projective spaces for a moment and let's think about points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I can denote such point by $(x,y)$. That's the usual notion. But I can also begin a book by writing something like "let $\to x,y \leftarrow$ denote a point of coordinates $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$". Of course that's a funny way of denoting what *you* call $(x,y)$, but you can understand that it means the same thing because the author *defined* it to mean the same thing.

Comment: The same thing happens for projective coordinates. I prefer to write what *you* call $[x,y,z]$ as $[x:y:z]$. @Blue prefers $x:y:z$. Some other people may prefer $(x,y,z)$. That's fine, as long as the author makes it clear what it should mean in any case.

Comment: Final comment which may be helpful: when we're talking about homogeneous coordinates, we're *always* talking about projective spaces.

Comment: but Lee Mosher said the homogeneous coordinates are the point of $\mathbb R^3$.so what is right?

Comment: He didn't; he said that a point in projective space is *represented* by points in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 

Let's be precise: a point in the projective space *is* a line passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, right? But, since there's only one line which passes through two given points, a point $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ *determines* a line (that is, a point of the projective space) which we denote by $[x:y:z]$. (Once again, you can denote this however you want, but let's fix this notation for now).

Comment: So... a point $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ *determines* a point $[x:y:z]$ in the projective space.

Comment: Lee Mosher said that "ordered triple $(x,y,z)∈R^3$ is called "homogeneous coordinates" for the point $[x:y:z]∈P^2.$" That means he said $(x,y,z)$ belongs to $R^3$?

Comment: Well... yes. We wrote $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. I really don't get why you're focusing on this. That's just notation. Of course good notation is important, but it shouldn't be the main focus.

Comment: because, you said homogenous coordinates belongs to $P^2$ and from by Lee answer we see it's belongs to $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: I agree that this phrase that you cited is a little strange. Homogeneous coordinates define elements of $\mathbb{P}^2$. I'm absolutely sure that Lee understands perfectly well what he's saying; he just wrote a strange phrase.